# ADFS Custom claim not not returning NameID

Tags: adfs

I am attempting to use custom claims to create a SAML function with our application.

- The first claim converts the SamAccountName to NameID and stores it
- The second claim will convert it to a transient SPNameQualifier

Below are my custom claims in order.

- The error received is NameID Properties Null
- It looks like my first claim is not working correctly

Claim 1

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("NAMEID"), query = ";sAMAccountName;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

Claim 2

```
c:[Type == "NAMEID"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuerC = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient");
```

Error

```
The SAML authentication request had a NameID Policy that could not be satisfied. 
Requestor: tenable.sc 
Name identifier format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient 
SPNameQualifier:  
Exception details: 
MSIS7070: The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: True Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient SPNameQualifier: . Actual NameID properties: null. 

This request failed. 

User Action 
Use the AD FS Management snap-in to configure the configuration that emits the required name identifier.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use a string rather than a URI.

So I would use a Transform rule - transforming sAMAccountName to NameID of format "transient".